# 2d array passed to function not assigning value

Tags: c++, arrays

So I am trying to read a simple text file. The file has 
Name,Score,Plays

When I call the function the first line works great.  The next line doesnt work.  However see that I read the values into temp.  Temp has the correct info it just doesnt assign to the array that was passed to it.  It seems the array has the value of the 1st line, like after line one they all get the same value.

For example the text file looks like this:
one,1,2
two,3,4

In the function the first line reads and goes into the array as expected.

The next line and others do not.  The value temp is correct and was read from the file properly how it did not go into the array

```
int numberOfScore = 0;
char scoreName[10][35];
int scoreScore[10];
int scorePlays[10];


// load and previous scores
scoreRead( scoreName,  scoreScore,  scorePlays,  numberOfScore );
```

Above is the call and below is the function.

```
void scoreRead(char scoreName[][35], int scoreScore[], int scorePlays[],  int &numberOfScore )
{
     char temp[35];

    ifstream ifs;

    numberOfScore=0;

    ifs.clear();
    ifs.open("gameScore.txt");


    if (ifs.good())
    {

        do {

            ifs.clear();

            ifs.getline(temp , MAX_STR_LEN,  ',');

            strcpy(scoreName[numberOfScore],temp);


            ifs.getline(temp, MAX_STR_LEN, ',');
            scoreScore[numberOfScore] = atoi(temp);

            ifs.getline(temp, MAX_STR_LEN);
            scorePlays[numberOfScore] = atoi(temp);

            numberOfScore ++;


        } while (ifs.good());

    }


    ifs.close();

}
```

Comment: Stepping line by line using gdb (or F9/F10/F11 on MSVC) and spot the value changes would solve this problem, and many future problems.

Comment: well before I put any questions on here I try everything.  If the debugger would have helped me I wouldnt have posted.  For now I made the vars global, but it still needs to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you were trying to do and why it did not work.
The arrays have the desired values inside the function, but once exit the function, the values in arrays are gone.

The reason this function failed to pass values back is that in C/C++, function parameters pass in values with your function prototype, with local variables created and shadowing your supposed-globals.

The reason you get the first line is that array name is treated as a pointer and can represent the first element (roughly speaking).

There are 3 ways to make this work.

```
1. make the variables global (easiest, and code posted below, but not suggested)
2. pass in pointers to array
3. pass in references to array
```

code for method 1:

```
$ cat getScore.cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#define MAX_STR_LEN 100
using namespace std;

int numberOfScore = 0;
char scoreName[10][35];
int scoreScore[10];
int scorePlays[10];

void scoreRead()
{
     char temp[35];

    ifstream ifs;

    numberOfScore=0;

    ifs.clear();
    ifs.open("gameScore.txt");


    if (ifs.good())
    {

        do {

            ifs.clear();

            ifs.getline(temp , MAX_STR_LEN,  ',');

cout<<temp<<endl;
            strcpy(scoreName[numberOfScore],temp);
cout<<scoreName[numberOfScore]<<endl;

            ifs.getline(temp, MAX_STR_LEN, ',');
            scoreScore[numberOfScore] = atoi(temp);
cout<<scoreScore[numberOfScore]<<endl;
            ifs.getline(temp, MAX_STR_LEN);
            scorePlays[numberOfScore] = atoi(temp);

cout<<scorePlays[numberOfScore]<<endl;
            numberOfScore ++;
cout<<numberOfScore<<endl;

        } while (ifs.good());

    }


    ifs.close();

}

int main(){

// load and previous scores
scoreRead();
cout<<cout<<scoreName[1]<<endl;
return 0;
}
```